# magento save checkout onepage custom step data without creating a new column in quote table

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, quote, quoteitem, sales-quote

I have created a new custom step on checkout onepage and want to save the data of custom step. Is there any other option than creating a new column in quote tables and saving data there.

Comment: Try this

    https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-custom-steps-to-checkout.html

    http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/10/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step/

Comment: I already have added custom step and your reference link shows how to add step. But I want to save the data of it in quote table without creating any new column because all checkout data we enter get save to quote tables.